# Oracle, inserting rows by using Max+1 of the existing field

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I am pretty new to oracle.
I have to insert a row using a value of (max + 1) from the existing field. 
Does anyone has any idea on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
SQL> create table t (col) as (select 4 from dual union all select 9 from dual);

Table created.

SQL> select * from t;

       COL
----------
         4
         9

2 rows selected.

SQL> insert into t values (1 + (select max(col) from t));

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t;

       COL
----------
         4
         9
        10

3 rows selected.
```

Comment: Exactly, and lots of thanks. So, if i have more columns should it be sth like insert into t (col , a )values (1 + (select max(col) from t), 'somevalue') ; ?

Comment: Hi Chit,   -   not sure what you mean, exactly. If you have two columns in the table, you want to insert a new row - do you want to insert max + 1 from one of the two columns, what do you want to insert in the other column (in the new row)? An example would help. Cheers!

Comment: Any value. It should be something that the user input.

Comment: Are you trying to use this column as a primary key? Oracle has a feature called "sequences" exactly for this purpose. In a multi-user environment, the way you are trying to re-create that concept through brute force may lead to problems. What if a user creates a new row, uses the next available value for the column (max + 1), but before this user commits, another user also tries to create a new row and uses the same max+1? Let Oracle do the work for you. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6015.htm

Comment: nope it can be duplicate, but i have some conditions where the value should add +1, i am wondering whether i should handle in backend or as a store procedure (I am not quite sure how to write a store procedure yet)